# Given list of dicts, an efficient way to print out keys once, then all values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

So I've got a list of dicts.  I'd like to print out the first dict's keys (which are guaranteed to be the same in each dict), then all their values (which aren't).  Logic:

```
key1,key2,key3,...
dicts[0][key1],dicts[0][key2],dicts[0][key3],...
dicts[1][key1],dicts[1][key2],dicts[1][key3],...
...
```

Output:

```
last_modified,asset_id,asset_type,asset_name,status,annotation,error_id
2013-10-31 10:30:56,745844,VECTOR,Diameters,PROCESS_STOPPED,SYSTEM_ERROR,1376
2013-10-31 04:53:17,750686,VECTOR,bogus_data_1,PROCESS_STOPPED,SYSTEM_ERROR,1382
...
```

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
errors = GetErrorList()
print 'last_modified,asset_id,asset_type,asset_name,status,annotation,error_id'
for error in errors:
  print '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (
    error['last_modified'], error['asset_id'], error['asset_type'],
    error['asset_name'], error['status'], error['annotation'], error['error_id']
  )
```

Hardcoding the keys twice seems inefficient and breakage-prone, but the output order is fixed, so I can't just dump out `errors[0].keys()`.  Is there a nicer/more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys = ('last_modified', 'asset_id', 'asset_type', 'asset_name', 'status', 'annotation', 'error_id')
print ','.join(keys)
for error in GetErrorList():
    print ','.join(str(error[key]) for key in keys)
```

This prints commas between values like your desired output. Your program prints spaces.

If you'd rather have spaces, change the second `','` to `' '`.

Comment: Spectacular, and like all good solutions, obvious in hindsight.  Thank you!

Comment: Two minor tweaks: you're missing a ) at the end of the first line, and you need `str(error[key])` be able to join non-string values together.

Comment: Your formatting string seems to indicate they are all strings.

Comment: Yes, this wasn't clear from my question, but eg. `last_modified` is a datetime object that gets munged into a string through `%s` in the original.